# Detail in Lemma 6.13 pag. 190 from Isaacs Book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm all right in the proof till the point in which he says: the group $\langle a^2\rangle$ can contain no element of order $4$.

First: what does "CAN CONTAIN NO ELEMENT etc" mean exactly? English is not my mother tongue, however I think, literally, it seems that it means "there is the possibility that $\langle a^2\rangle$ doesen't contain any element of order $4$", or equivalently "$\langle a^2\rangle$ doesen't contain necessarely elements of order $4$". But this does not convince me. To me it would be more reasonable if this mean "$\langle a^2\rangle$ doesn't contain any element of order $4$".

Second: suppose what I meant is right ($\langle a^2\rangle$ doesn't contain any element of order $4$), let's understand why. If by contradiction 
$\langle a^2\rangle$ contain some such element, say $a^{2j}$, then it would be inverted by $a$, i.e. $(a^{2j})^a=a^{-2j}$, i.e. $a^{2j}=a^{-2j}$, i.e. $a^{4j}=1$. But from this I can't reach any contradiction.
Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: It means that $\forall x\in \langle a^2\rangle\left[(x\neq 1\land x^2\neq 1)\implies x^4\neq 1\right]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The sentence means

> The group $\langle a^2 \rangle$ does not contain any element of order 4

In answer to your second question: If $a^{2j}$ has order 4, then $a^{4j} = (a^{2j})^2 \neq 1$.

Comment: Thank Dane.... I'm very very tired :-P